# How can I make a menu option expand in android?

Tags: android

I wrote this code in `mainactivty.java`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    menu.add("About");
    return true;
}
```

It creates a menu, but I want it to open a new window when I click on the menu.

Comment: do you mean that you want it to create a new window when the user taps the MENU button? Or do you want it to open a new window when the user taps one of the items IN the menu that pops up when they tap the menu button?

Comment: I want to open a new window when the user taps one of the items IN the menu that pops up when they tap the menu button can u help Dr.Dredel ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want (cause it seems too obvious) but it sounds like you're asking for the following

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   switch (item.getItemId()) {

     case R.id.someItem: //this is your menu item in the menu.xml
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class)); //here you start your new activity
     break;
   }
}
```